# Weird SEGFAULT while loading DLL under gdb

Tags: c, dll, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have a small C program that loads a custom DLL and uses a couple of functions. I can run the program from the console and it works as intended. (I'm compiling with MinGW on Windows XP)

But if I run it from gdb, when it gets to loading the DLL, I get:

```
56              ldll = LoadLibrary("gsp810.dll");
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x7c929af2 in ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
```

The weird thing is, if I make a **backtrace** at this point, I get a strange stack of Windows functions, which doesn't even contain my own program's stack (see below). However, if I keep running, it'll eventually return to my main() function and everything seems to be back to normal. The program works as expected and the functions from the DLL can be called.

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x7c929af2 in ntdll!RtlpWaitForCriticalSection () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#1  0x7c911046 in ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#2  0x00e161a0 in ?? ()
#3  0x77da6cf8 in RegCloseKey () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll
#4  0x77da78e4 in RegOpenKeyExA () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\advapi32.dll
#5  0x77f44fcd in SHLWAPI!PathMakeSystemFolderW () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll
#6  0x77f452e8 in SHLWAPI!PathMakeSystemFolderW () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll
#7  0x77f45252 in SHLWAPI!PathMakeSystemFolderW () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\shlwapi.dll
#8  0x7c91118a in ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#9  0x77f40000 in ?? ()
#10 0x7c92b5d2 in ntdll!LdrFindResourceDirectory_U () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#11 0x7c9262db in ntdll!RtlValidateUnicodeString () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#12 0x7c92643d in ntdll!LdrLoadDll () from C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
#13 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Is this SEGFAULT normal, or it is indicating an underlying problem with the DLL?

**EDIT:** Ok, looks like the problem is in the DLL itself. What I don't understand is the backtrace gdb is showing, as it does not contain the functions in my application. Then, at a certain point, it somehow "switches" to my stack, and the program keeps running as if nothing had happened.

Is it possible that Windows is somehow "handling" the segmentation fault, and the it returns control to the application?

Comment: Definitely not normal. I'd say the DLL is seg faulting in the DLL's entry point function.

Comment: There's no reason for the loading process to reference SHKWAPI. A DLL's entry point function must be attempting to, despite it being forbidden (you can only reference Kernel32 from a DllMain()).

Comment: @CareyGregory yes, looks like the DLL is causing it, but wouldn't this mean a crash of the application? or at least an error loading the library? if I hadn't run the application in gdb, I wouln't have even noticed..

Comment: can't you use gdb for setting up a break point at the start of DllMain?

Comment: Yes, if something crashes in `DLLMain`, it will take down the application. However, I've seen more than one case of crashes that can be reproduced only in a debugger, or only _not_ in a debugger. You might have such a situation here. I would put a breakpoint in `DllMain` like manuell suggested.